# How to post data if checkbox is not checked

Tags: woocommerce, customization, checkout

I put a checkbox in the checkout page of woocommerce.
If this is commercial order, customer will check it and will put tax number.

If it is checked, I can get "1" value in the database with below code.

But I also want to see "0" if the checkbox is not clicked.

How I can manage it?

```html
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'commercial_order_checkout_field');

function commercial_order_checkout_field($fields)
{
    $fields['billing']['commercial_order'] = array(
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'priority' => 8,
        'label'     => __('Kurumsal Sipariş', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    $fields['billing']['tax_number'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Vergi Dairesi', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'   => _x('Vergi Dairesi', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'class'     => array('form-row form-row-first'),
        'required' => true,
        'priority' => 31,
        'clear'     => true
    );

    return $fields;
}
// Save the custom checkout field in the order meta, when checkbox has been checked
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'commercial_order', $_POST['commercial_order'] );
}
```

Comment: See this line: `if ( ! empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) ) update_post_meta...` it says 'when NOT empty'.. So to answer your question, do the reverse when IT IS empty

Answer (score 0):

I solve it as below.

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['kurumsal_siparis'] ) ) {
         $faturatipi = "F";     
   } else {
         $faturatipi = "A";    
   }
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'mythra_fatura_tipi', $faturatipi );
}
```